# Laravel 5.5 return Parse Error when I grafted the variable into the HTML code

Tags: php, html, laravel

Laravel returns me a parse error when my controller returns a variable with inside the HTML code.
I have a switch that returns something like:

```
$badge =  '<a href="#" class="badge bg-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Critical</a>';
```

after that my controller must return this variable:

```
$btn = '<div class="dropdown">
"'.$badge.'"

<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">'.
 ( ($data->ipAddress !== '') ? '
 <a href="telnet://'.$ip.'" class="dropdown-item"><i class="mi-tv"></i> Telnet</a>
 <a href="ssh://'.$ip.'" class="dropdown-item"><i class="mi-tv"></i> SSH</a>'.
 '<a href="/AlarmMonitoring/PING/'.$ip.'" class="dropdown-item" target="_blank"><i class="mi-swap-horiz"></i> Ping</a><div class="dropdown-divider"></div>' : ''). 
 '<a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="detailsbtn" data-id="'.$data->evid.'"><i class="mi-view-list"></i> Device Details</a>
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="btnDeviceGraph" data-id="'.$data->device.'"><i class="icon-graph"></i> Device Graph</a>
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="btnInterfaceGraph" data-hostname="'.$data->device.'" data-component="'.$data->component.'"><i class="icon-graph"></i> Interface Graph</a>
 </div>
</div>'
return $btn;
```

before I added $badges inside the HTML, everything worked fine.
I think the problem is with how I grafted the variable into the HTML code. 
But I'm a little confused in the use of the quotes and double quotes for concatenation.

Can anyone help me understand where the error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have semicolon `;` at the end of your variable `$btn` declaration statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes here `"'.$badge.'"` like `'.$badge.'`

Comment: Laravel return the same error:  Parse error: syntax error

Comment: This morning I need a break!!!. I missed ; after the last </div>'

Comment: you forgot the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing a semicolon on the second last line.